# 404 error when trying to display the sql table content in the HTML webpage using Python flask

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I have created a simple BMI calculation application the code works for inserting records into a table but I can't able to display the records.

Here is my code. kindly, help me out to solve this issue.
this code successfully inserted records to table.but failed to display to the webpage.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,url_for,flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key="flash message"
app.config['MYSQL_HOST']='localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER']='root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']='mypassword'
app.config['MYSQL_DB']='bmicalculate'
mysql=MySQL(app)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/display',methods=['POST'])
def display():
    cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from userdetails")
    data=cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return render_template('display.html',data=data)


@app.route('/insert',methods=['POST'])
def insert():
    if request.method=="POST":
        name=request.form['name']
        age=request.form['age']
        weight=request.form['weight']
        height=request.form['height']
        weight=int(weight)
        height=int(height)
        bmi=((weight)/(height*height))*10000
        bmi=int(bmi)
        cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("insert into userdetails(name,age,weight,height,bmi) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name,age,weight,height,bmi))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BMI Application</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="{{url_for('static',filename='style.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <h1>BMI Calculation Web Development</h1>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="display">
            <a href="display.html" method="POST">
                <button>Display records</button>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="calculate">
            <h2>Enter your details</h2>
            <form action="{{url_for('insert')}}" method="POST">
                <div class="form">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form" name="name" placeholder="enter your name"  required="1"><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="form">
                    <label>Age:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form" name="age" placeholder="enter your age"  required="1"><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="form">
                    <label>Weight:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form" name="weight" placeholder="enter your weight in kgs"  required="1"><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="form">
                    <label>Height:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form" name="height" placeholder="enter your height in cm"  required="1"><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="form">
                    <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button><br><br>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

display.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>User Records</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
 
 td {
        width: 150px;
        color:blueviolet;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
      }
</style>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>BMI</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
     {% for row in data %}    
            <tr>
                <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your display route only works for POST requests, but your browser sends a get request.

```
@app.route('/display',methods=['POST'])
def display():
```

Either change `POST` to `GET` or remove the `methods=...` completely, as `GET` is the default anyway.

If this sounds confusing, have a look at the following article which explains the HTTP verbs

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

**Update**

You have to change your code to either

```
@app.route('/display',methods=['GET'])
def display():
```

or

```
@app.route('/display')
def display():
```

Comment: hello buddy thanks for answering. I have changed that methods to POST and tried to display but same error occurred next time I removed methods totally but that time also I got same error 404 the exact error was ,    **127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2021 19:28:26] "[33mGET /display.html HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -**

Comment: The error in the webpage was,    **Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.**

Comment: I will update my answer - and hope to make it even clearer.

Comment: Thanks for ur help.I have founded the error. Inside index.html  ```<div class="display">
            <a href="display.html" method="POST">
                <button>Display records</button>
            </a>
        </div>```      It should be given as display instead of display.html inside a tag ``` <a href="display.html" method="POST">``` It should be ``` <a href="display" method="POST">``` like this Hope this and is useful.

Comment: OK, so you had one more problem. Still, my answer is valid. You should change the route to `GET` and remove the `method="POST"` from your link.

Comment: yeah we should change